# Index differences for S3 URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a AWS bucket that I've setup with static website hosting.

Unfortunately I can see the index document within the Endpoint URL but not the other.

I can see the index here:
http://BUCKETNAME.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

But I cannot see it here.  I only see the XML listing:
http://BUCKETNAME.s3.amazonaws.com/

How do I see the non-XML page in the URL above?

Answer (score 1):

If you issue a GET request to the bucket endpoint, S3 understands that as a "list" request and, if authorized, will return the XML with the contents of the bucket.

If you enable static website hosting, you will get a different endpoint (...s3-website...) and in that endpoint a GET request will return your index document.

Comment: Usually you would alias the website endpoint to your domain name using a CNAME or ALIAS record in your DNS service (Route53?)...